# Check if all listed packages are installed in bash

Tags: shell, apt, dpkg

My binary depends on these boost libraries and respective packages:

```
NAME                                  |          PACKAGE:
--------------------------------------+-----------------------------------
libboost_serialization.so.1.55.0      |  libboost-serialization1.55.0
libboost_thread.so.1.55.0             |  ibboost-thread1.55.0
libboost_date_time.so.1.55.0          |  libboost-date-time1.55.0
libboost_signals.so.1.55.0            |  libboost-signals1.55.0
```

So I'd like to define a list of packages:

```
boostlibnames="libboost-serialization1.55.0 libboost-thread1.55.0 libboost-date-time1.55.0 libboost-signals1.55.0"
```

And now I'd like to check if they are all installed and only then run actual `apt-get install`. I know apt will automatically check whether the packages are already installed, but I'd like to place in a prompt to the user whether he wants to install missing libraries before doing so.

So is there a nice way to check whether all listed libraries (in variable as above) are installed?

Comment: Create a proper Debian package and let apt handle the dependencies

Comment: @ivanivan It's an internal company application and of course not open-source.

Comment: Doesn't mean that you have to distribute the deb file or anything else beyond your internal company ... just use the packaging systems dependency resolving.  Heck, use the method on this q/a to create a fake package to get the deps installed - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318117/create-a-deb-package-with-only-dependencies

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `dpkg -s` command returns the status of installed packages. For example, on my system, if I run it for `firefox` which is installed and `nedit` which isn't, I get:

```
$ dpkg -s firefox
Package: firefox
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: web
Installed-Size: 94341
Maintainer: Clement Lefebvre <root@linuxmint.com>
Architecture: amd64
Version: 41.0~linuxmint1+betsy
Replaces: firefox-l10n-af, firefox-l10n-ar, firefox-l10n-be, firefox-l10n-bg, firefox-l10n-bn-bd, firefox-l10n-ca, firefox-l10n-cs, firefox-l10n-da, firefox-l10n-de, firefox-l10n-el, firefox-l10n-en-gb, firefox-l10n-en-us, firefox-l10n-eo, firefox-l10n-es, firefox-l10n-et, firefox-l10n-eu, firefox-l10n-fa, firefox-l10n-fi, firefox-l10n-fr, firefox-l10n-fy, firefox-l10n-gl, firefox-l10n-gu, firefox-l10n-he, firefox-l10n-hi, firefox-l10n-hr, firefox-l10n-hu, firefox-l10n-id, firefox-l10n-is, firefox-l10n-it, firefox-l10n-ja, firefox-l10n-kn, firefox-l10n-ko, firefox-l10n-lt, firefox-l10n-lv, firefox-l10n-nb, firefox-l10n-nl, firefox-l10n-nn, firefox-l10n-pl, firefox-l10n-pt, firefox-l10n-pt-br, firefox-l10n-ro, firefox-l10n-ru, firefox-l10n-sk, firefox-l10n-sl, firefox-l10n-sq, firefox-l10n-sr, firefox-l10n-sv, firefox-l10n-th, firefox-l10n-tr, firefox-l10n-uk, firefox-l10n-zh
Provides: gnome-www-browser, www-browser
Breaks: firefox-l10n-en-us
Description: The Firefox web browser
 The Mozilla Firefox Web Browser.

$ dpkg -s nedit
dpkg-query: package 'nedit' is not installed and no information is available
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

So, you can use that command to check whether a package is installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

run_install()
{
    ## Prompt the user 
    read -p "Do you want to install missing libraries? [Y/n]: " answer
    ## Set the default value if no answer was given
    answer=${answer:Y}
    ## If the answer matches y or Y, install
    [[ $answer =~ [Yy] ]] && apt-get install ${boostlibnames[@]}
}

boostlibnames=("libboost-serialization1.55.0" "libboost-thread1.55.0"
                "libboost-date-time1.55.0" "libboost-signals1.55.0" "nedit")
## Run the run_install function if sany of the libraries are missing
dpkg -s "${boostlibnames[@]}" >/dev/null 2>&1 || run_install
```

Comment: Is there some short way to save results? Eg. in C/C++ I'd do `installed = installed || isInstalled(libArray[i])`. So similarly, I'd like to put false in a variable if one or more were not installed. I think I can do this with `if`, but that's a lot of code for nothing.

Comment: @TomášZato yes, but you'll have to be more specific. Do you want to save the list of missing libraries? Is just one enough? Personally, I would just check whether all are installed and if at least one isn't, run `apt-get install` on all of them. Any that are installed will simply be ignored. Let me know what you want and I'll edit this. Basically, you'll need to change the `|| echo ...` to `|| installed=1` or something.

Comment: I wanted to do exactly what you do, it's wasted effort to save list of missing libraries. Just check'em all, and if any is missing, prompt user for apt-get. I already got your code working with ugly `if` statement, but variable would be preffered. I plan on wraping it into a function.

Comment: @TomášZato OK, have a look at the updated answer. I simplified it a bit since `dpkg -s` can check for multiple packages at once.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code in my work called the [Easy Bash](https://github.com/terrylinooo/easybash), which helps install the most popular packages quicky on Ubuntu servers. This code will check the listed packages installed or not.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

packages=("curl" "gnupg2" "ca-certificates" "lsb-release")

for pkg in ${packages[@]}; do

    is_pkg_installed=$(dpkg-query -W --showformat='${Status}\n' ${pkg} | grep "install ok installed")

    if [ "${is_pkg_installed}" == "install ok installed" ]; then
        echo ${pkg} is installed.
    fi
done
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Still, please avoid posting [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), and copy-and-pase it with proper formatting instead ...

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you a list of all relevant packages which *aren't* installed:

```
dpkg -l $boostlibnames 2>&1 | awk '{if (/^D|^\||^\+/) {next} else if(/^dpkg-query:/) { print $6} else if(!/^[hi]i/) {print $2}}'
```

This skips `dpkg -l`'s header lines, and then prints out lines where dpkg-query complains about a an unknown package, AND lines *not* beginning with `hi` or `ii` (Hold Inst or Install Inst).

Usually, I'd do something like `awk 'NR<=5 {next} ; ...'` or `sed -e '1,5d'` to get rid of `dpkg -l`'s header lines but in this case we're redirecting stderr to stdout in order to catch complaints by `dpkg-query` as well as `dpkg -l`'s output, so we can't simply delete the first 5 lines.

This will show packages either never installed, removed, purged, or where the install has failed / partially-completed due to error.

Answer (score 1):

I did this function for a CentOS system today.

```
#!/bin/bash

# List of the packages that should be present
list=("vim-enhanced" "nano" "expect" "dialog" "epel-release" "yum-utils" "bind-utils")

# Check for the existence of the packages in the system and print to file.txt the packages to be installed
check_list=$(rpm -q "${list[@]}" | grep -e "not installed" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { print $2}' > list.txt)

# Check if the list.txt is empty
grep -q '[^[:space:]]' < list.txt
EMPTY_FILE=$?
# If list.txt is empty there's nothing to do
if [[ $EMPTY_FILE -eq 1 ]]; then

echo "Nothing to do"

else

# If list.txt is not empty it installs the packages in list.txt

for PACKAGES in `cat /your/path/list.txt`; do

  yum install -y $PACKAGES

done

fi
```

Well, i slightly modified the function. Faster and it does not need a loop anymore.

```
#!/bin/bash


list=("vim-enhanced" "nano" "expect" "dialog" "epel-release" "yum-utils" "bind-utils")
check_list=$(rpm -q "${list[@]}" | grep -e "not installed" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = " " } ; { printf $2" "}' > /your/path/to/list.txt)
install=$(cat /your/path/to/list.txt)

grep -q '[^[:space:]]' < /your/path/to/list.txt

EMPTY_FILE=$?

if [[ $EMPTY_FILE -eq 1 ]]; then

echo "Nothing to do"

else

yum install -y $install

fi
```

The Debian/Ubuntu counterpart:

```
apt -qq YOUR_LIST_GOES_HERE | grep -v "installed" | awk -F/ '{print $1}' > /your/path/to/list.txt
packages=$(cat /your/path/to/list.txt)
grep -q '[^[:space:]]' < /your/path/to/list.txt
EMPTY_FILE=$?
if [[ $EMPTY_FILE -eq 1 ]]; then
echo "Nothing to do"
else
apt-get  install -y $packages
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#to check package is installed or not without distribution dependency
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Package Name: " pkg
which $pkg > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? == 0 ]
then
echo "$pkg is already installed. "
else
read -p "$pkg is not installed. Answer yes/no if want installation_ " request
if  [ $request == "yes" ]
then
yum install $pkg
fi
fi
```

Comment: The question was **not** about checking if a single package is already installed.