# Create a .deb package with only dependencies

Tags: debian, apt

I have a piece of software that comes as a deb package or as source. I would like to install it from source so I can install it in a non-standard directory, but would like to use apt for dependency management.

Is there software that I can use that will create a deb package from another that is just a dummy package with the dependencies for the package?

EDIT: To clarify, I want to satisfy the dependencies of the software, not use the software to satisfy dependencies.

Comment: Probably https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30303/how-to-create-a-deb-file-manually might be helpful.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `equivs` for that. Install the [`equivs`](https://tracker.debian.org/equivs) package, and run

```
equivs-control yourpackage.control
```

(replacing `yourpackage` with something appropriate for your situation).

This will create a template `yourpackage.control` file; edit it as appropriate:

- to enforce dependencies, list them in the `Depends:` line;
- to satisfy dependencies, list them in the `Provides:` line (adding it if necessary).

If you want to satisfy a single dependency, name your package accordingly, don’t `Provide` it.

You should also fill in the `Version:` line. Then run

```
equivs-build yourpackage.control
```

and install the resulting `.deb` package (which will enforce the dependencies).